# Why isn't this file opening?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Try stuffing this code into files index.html, style.css and app.js, it doesn't open. The browser says that "The webpage was reloaded because a problem occurred" and keeps on loading.I am using an MacBook Air with macOS Big Sur with an M1, if that's of any help. I removed the full HTML code and rewrote it again, and found out it is the javascript that is causing the issue. But I have no idea why, because 1) I think my code is correct and 2) I can't open the console to check for errors because the file doesn't open. Could anybody help me?

My HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="./app.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="type" contenteditable="true">In .type</div>
    <div class="words">In .words</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript file is:

```
const type = document.querySelector(".type");
const words = document.querySelector(".words");

console.log(type.innerHTML.split(""));

for (let i=0; i < type.innerHTML.split("").length; i++) {
    type.innerHTML += `<span>${i}</span>`
}
```

And my css file is:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=JetBrains+Mono&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #333;
}

.type, .words { 
    font-family: 'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #007bff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 100px;
    outline: none;
}

.type {
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}

.words {
    background-color: #333;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Describe "doesn't open"...

Comment: Right. The browser says that "The webpage was reloaded because a problem occurred" and keeps on loading.

Comment: the problem may be with the server, nothing stands out in that code that would cause that error (there's probably an error because your javascript runs before the page loads, but that won't cause a reload)

Comment: I tried to do it on another computer, it still doesn't work :(

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Safari. But it doesn't work in Microsoft Edge and Chrome.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol I have edited the question

Comment: that's happened with both files or only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a loop on element `type` and updating it in loop.
You have created an endless loop my friend.

Try changing this-

```
for (let i=0; i < type.innerHTML.split("").length; i++) {
    type.innerHTML += `<span>${i}</span>`
}
```

to this-

```
let typesplit = type.innerHTML.split("")
for (let i=0; i < typesplit.length ; i++) {
    type.innerHTML += `<span>${i}</span>`
}
```

This way it won't update the value of `.type` every time.

Also try not to use `type` as variable name as it is a reserved word in `Typescript` which resembles `JavaScript`.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to change the type` variable's value to <span>${i}</span>, not words.

Comment: just stopping by to say that putting the condition in a separate variable like `let typesplit = type.innerHTML.split("")` is a really good point

Comment: @Anonymouse `.type` has value of `In .type` so it should give `01234567` but in the code you mentioned it gives an enormous value.

Comment: @KeshavBajaj any ideas how I could do what my first comment says?

Comment: I have edited the code, please look carefully.